# Rails 3.2.11 asset pipeline: accented characters in javascript get converted to question marks in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, asset-pipeline, pipeline, assets

I'm writing a rails application in Spanish and I'm having trouble displaying accented characters from JavaScript.

Everything works fine in development, but in production, in the unified `/public/assets/application[*fingerprint*].js` file, all my special Spanish characters get converted to question marks. I have triple checked that my .js files are indeed in UTF-8, and have also tried changing the extension to .js.erb and putting `<%# encoding: utf-8 %>` at the top of the files, but still no joy.

I created a new, simple application from scratch just to test this and the problem persists. I've even tried disabling the uglifier gem, just in case, and that didn't work either. My main suspect now is Sprockets, but can't find any information of this happening to anyone else. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Have you set a locale ?

Comment: You mean in the OS? I hadn't, but now I've changed it to es_ES.utf-8 and the problem persists. If you meant inside Rails, I haven't tried that yet (I'm pretty much a Rails n00b and haven't touched I18n yet... maybe I should focus on that next?)

Comment: Try in your `config/environments/production` , there is a commented setting `config.I18n.default_locale` , change it to your locale , according to [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: I added the line `config.i18n.default_locale = :es` to `config/application.rb` as it seemed to make more sense there, but although my application now reports the locale to be _es_ instead of _en_ but the special characters are still missing.

Comment: Debian Wheezy. Sorry, that comment was supposed to be more elaborate, but I pressed enter and that created the post instead of inserting a paragraph. My lack of experience in Stackoverflow shows once more, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, I made further tests and have managed to close in on the culprit. It seems to be the JS runtime (either execJS or the rubyrhino, I'm in the process of installing and testing therubyracer). Right now, if I include something like `<%=  eval_js "'El camión del niño'" %>`in a view, I get _El cami?n del ni?o_.

Comment: Really glad to hear it , good luck .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally got it working by replacing Rhino with Node.js (I'm required to use jRuby so therubyracer was apparently not a good option either).

==============================================

UPDATE: It's been quite a while and I had pretty much forgotten about this post, but now I have come across it again I feel there's something I should mention: Although my original solution of using Node.js worked, it turned out to be more of an inadverted workaround than anything else.

As I found out some time later, the source of the problem was that, due to my lack of experience with Linux, I was pretty sure that the locale was set up properly when it wasn't at all. Once I configured my locale correctly, it fixed this and quite a few other locale-related problems I was experiencing.